# what is the state of the art algorithm to encrypt credit card data

Tags: security, encryption

We have a business requirement to keep credit card data. What is today's (Nov 2013) state of the art algorithm to encrypt credit card data that will be saved on disk?
Additionally, I'd appreciate pointers to Java libraries that implement these algorithms

Note that we are PCI compliant and we already store credit card data. I am doing a review to make sure that our encryption method remains state-of-the-art

Answer (score 1):

As @gauravphoenix points out, it is actually quite easy to go wrong with AES. The AES algorithm itself can only securely encrypt exactly 16 bytes of data if you give it a totally random key. If your problem is anything other than that (and almost everyone's problem is something different than that), you need to add more pieces to it. Specifically you need to choose an appropriate mode, configure that mode correctly, properly generate a key, and protect against modification. AES does none of this for you automatically, and unfortunately, most example code on the internet does it incorrectly.

There are a few libraries that attempt to bundle all of these details for you so that you can just make the silly "please encrypt this data" call that most people would like to make. I maintain one for iOS called [RNCryptor](https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor). There are a bunch of ports of the format to other languages, including a Java implementation called [JNCryptor](https://code.google.com/p/jncryptor/).

Another good "whole solution" AES implementation is [aescrypt](http://www.aescrypt.com), which includes a Java implementation.

Note that the most important technical(*) step of securing the data is not your selection of algorithm or format. It's how you manage the keys. If you store the key on the same disk as the credit card numbers, or hard-code it into your software, then it doesn't really matter how strong your encryption is. The state of the art in key management is called an HSM (Hardware Security Module). Companies like SafeNet make them. They can be rack-mounted, plug-in cards, or even USB dongles. I've worked with the [Luna](http://www.safenet-inc.com/products/data-protection/hardware-security-modules/luna-sa/), and was generally pleased with it, but there are several options on the market.

(*) While key management is IMO the most important technical step, it is by far not the most important step in securing credit cards (or anything else). The most important step is having procedures in place that encourage secure design, pre- and post-release security review, and a commitment to remediation of security findings.

Answer (score 0):

I recently just left the credit card industry as a developer to work in security in non PCI compliant field. BCrypt is a great choice. It allows a one way hash as well as a work parameter that forces time per attempt. This allows you to stop brut force attacks.

Comment: I should have clarified that we need to decrypt the credit card data. My understanding is that BCrypt is a 1-way hashing algorithm, and thsu would not meet our requirement

Comment: In what scenarios do you need to decrypt? One solution if someone does a balance check is to hash the input and compare to the DB stored hashes to find the match. The other benefit to bcrypt is that encrypting the same value always gives a different hash due to time; there are ways to still match however.

Comment: If you still do not want to use bcrypt you can use AES. At our company we changed over to bcrypt however. We kept the original card numbers stored in a datawarehouse that could only be accessed internally, and with one secured password for our security officer. All other systems used the hash in another table. We were PCI LEVEL 1...

Comment: We need to decrypt the credit card number to get the original value in the clear (not just do the equivalent of password validation by comparing hashes). This is used internally only.

Answer (score 0):

I would use one of the block ciphers approved by ISO/IEC 18033: AES, Camellia, and SEED.

It's hard to go wrong with AES256.

Comment: Just make sure you use enough rounds. https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/07/another_new_aes.html

Answer (score 0):

Just go ahead with AES 256 but make sure you choose right mode. I don't agree with comment "It's hard to go wrong with AES256." Check out - https://pthree.org/2012/02/17/ecb-vs-cbc-encryption/

Needless to say, you need to take care of key management and avoid any issues with IV- a message "hello world" encrypted with a key1+IV1 combination will look exactly the same in ciphertext every time you run your encryption. So make sure you are choosing your IVs randomly from a large entropy pool

From Java implementation perspective, Java has native support for AES encryption. Just make sure if you are using 256 bit encryption, you have the right unlimited strength JCE files - without these JCE files which provide crypto methods, you will be limited to 128 bit encryption.

Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551158/is-aes256-encryption-decryption-possible-in-java-without-unlimited-strength-jce) if you don't want to reply upon these JCE files available on server running your application.